# Angular JS slowness with IE and iPad

Tags: angularjs

Starting using Angular, and noticing with the full DOM parsing that it does that it seems to be slow when included on a large page.  This issue seems to be very relevant with IE, while not so much with FF or Chrome.

Has anyone found a way to:

- Not parse the whole DOM
- Clever solution make angular work faster on IE9+

Is there anyway to have angular only parse a sub section of the DOM specified via tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include less in the DOM at once :-)

Try paginating your super long lists, or split the UI you're displaying into multiple pages.

Also you could try `bindonce` https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce if you have a list of data that's static after being rendered.